# Getting error when using WebView on Xamarin.MAC

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

When i try to log in to my google account i get this error.I am using WebView on Xamarin.MacOS

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxLxZ.png)

```
<controls:WebViewer x:Name="webView" Source="{Binding Url}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                Navigated="Web_OnNavigated"
                                Navigating="Web_OnNavigating" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

There is how i add WebViewer

```
public class WebViewer : WebView
{
    public static BindableProperty GetCookiesProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(GetCookies), typeof(Func<string, CookieContainer>), typeof(CookieContainer),
            null, BindingMode.OneWayToSource);

    public static BindableProperty EvaluateJavascriptProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EvaluateJavascript), typeof(Func<string, Task<string>>), typeof(WebViewer),
            null, BindingMode.OneWayToSource);

    public Func<string, CookieContainer> GetCookies
    {
        get => (Func<string, CookieContainer>) GetValue(GetCookiesProperty);
        set => SetValue(GetCookiesProperty, value);
    }

    public Func<string, Task<string>> EvaluateJavascript
    {
        get => (Func<string, Task<string>>) GetValue(EvaluateJavascriptProperty);
        set => SetValue(EvaluateJavascriptProperty, value);
    }
}
```

There is my definition of WebViewer

and this is my url what im using to log in

```
Url = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/signinchooser?service=youtube&hl=en&passive=true&ltmpl=music&continue=https://www.youtube.com/signin?app=desktop&hl=en&feature=__FEATURE__&action_handle_signin=true&next=https%3A%2F%2Fmusic.youtube.com%2F&uilel=3&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin";
```

Mb you know any better analogs of webView what will work on MacOS?
URL is valid.I have same project on Windows with CefSharp and it works without any issues.I am trying to do log in form on my MACOS desktop application but it fail when im trying to log in.I am not using Oauth,user is logging in using his credentials,i get cookies,and when i use web api of youtube(unofficial)

Comment: Google has blocked OAuth requests via embedded browsers for about 2 years now, you have to launch an external browser and then get the redirected auth token to use in your app. You should review the source of Google's official `GTMAppAuth` (https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth) to see how it is done. Note: Xamarin.Auth still does not support macOS (there is an open issue that is over a year old)

Comment: @SushiHangover,i have same project on Windows and it works properly.I am not using oauth,user is logging in using his credentials,i get cookies,and when i use web api of youtube(unofficial)